# No puedo desplegar una aplicación escrita en Symfony 7 en hosting compartido con deployer: "Script cache:clear returned with error code 255"

Tags: php, composer, symfony7, deployer-php

Estoy intentando desplegar una aplicación basada en Symfony 7 en un hosting compartido (Inmotion Hosting). Todo sucede normalmente, pero al final falla con el error:

```
...
[im] > post-package-install: Symfony\Flex\Flex->recordFlexInstall
[im] > post-package-install: Symfony\Flex\Flex->recordFlexInstall
[im] > post-package-install: Symfony\Flex\Flex->recordFlexInstall
[im] > post-package-install: Symfony\Flex\Flex->recordFlexInstall
[im] > post-package-install: Symfony\Flex\Flex->recordFlexInstall
[im] Generating autoload files
[im] > pre-autoload-dump: Google\Task\Composer::cleanup
[im] Removing 277 google services
[im] > post-autoload-dump: Symfony\Component\Runtime\Internal\ComposerPlugin->updateAutoloadFile
[im] 122 packages you are using are looking for funding.
[im] Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
[im] > post-install-cmd: Symfony\Flex\Flex->install
[im] Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.
[im] > post-install-cmd: @auto-scripts
[im] > auto-scripts: Symfony\Flex\Flex->executeAutoScripts
[im] Executing script cache:clear
[im] Executed script cache:clear  [KO]
[im] [KO]
[im] Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
[im] !!
[im] Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
[im] exit code 255 (Unknown error)
ERROR: Task deploy:vendors failed!
task deploy:failed
task deploy:unlock
```

Al parecer los archivos se suben al servidor remoto, de hecho se crea una carpeta `releases` con subcarpetas numéricas que van aumentando según los intentos de despliegue y en cada una de ellas todas las carpetas y archivos de la aplicación.

Inicié sesión a través de `ssh` en el **servidor remoto** y luego fui a la última carpeta en `releases` e intenté ejecutar:

```
composer install
```

Y la salida fue esta:

```
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
> Google\Task\Composer::cleanup
122 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!  Composer detected issues in your platform:
!!  
!!  Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.2.0". You are running 8.1.27.
!!  
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
```

Como se puede entender por el mensaje: *`Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.2.0". You are running 8.1.27`*, el error se debe a la versión de PHP. Y esto es correcto, porque PHP 8.2 es la versión mínima para aplicaciones escritas en Symfony 7. Pero es que la versión de mi servidor remoto es la 8.2.15, por lo que entiendo que no debería ocurrir este problema. Para comprobarlo, al ejecutar en la consola del servidor remoto: `php -v` la salida es:

```
PHP 8.2.15 (cli) (built: Jan 25 2024 10:22:12) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.15, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v13.0.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2023, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend OPcache v8.2.15, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Entonces no entiendo por qué este error, por qué composer intenta una versión de PHP que no es la que está instalada y quisiera saber cómo resolverlo.

Intentando el comando:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs -vvv
```

El mensaje anterior desaparece, pero sigue fallando y composer sigue tomando, no sé por qué, la versión 8.1:

```
Running 2.6.5 (2023-10-06 10:11:52) with PHP 8.1.27 on Linux / 4.18.0-425.19.2.lve.el7h.x86_64
Reading ./composer.json (/home/MYSHARED/MYFOLDER/releases/3/composer.json)
Loading config file ./composer.json (/home/MYSHARED/MYFOLDER/releases/3/composer.json)
Checked CA file /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem: valid
Executing command (/home/MYSHARED/MYFOLDER/releases/3): 'git' 'branch' '-a' '--no-color' '--no-abbrev' '-v'
Executing command (/home/MYSHARED/MYFOLDER/releases/3): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (CWD): git --version
Executing command (/home/MYSHARED/MYFOLDER/releases/3): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD --no-show-signature
Executing command (/home/MYSHARED/MYFOLDER/releases/3): hg branch
Executing command (/home/MYSHARED/MYFOLDER/releases/3): fossil branch list
Executing command (/home/MYSHARED/MYFOLDER/releases/3): fossil tag list
Executing command (/home/MYSHARED/MYFOLDER/releases/3): svn info --xml
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /home/MYSHARED/.config/composer/composer.json

Reading /home/MYSHARED/MYFOLDER/releases/3/vendor/composer/installed.json
Loading plugin Symfony\Flex\Flex (from symfony/flex)
Loading plugin Symfony\Component\Runtime\Internal\ComposerPlugin (from symfony/runtime)
Reading ./composer.lock (/home/MYSHARED/MYFOLDER/releases/3/composer.lock)
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Reading ./composer.lock (/home/MYSHARED/MYFOLDER/releases/3/composer.lock)
> pre-pool-create: Symfony\Flex\Flex->truncatePackages
Reading /home/MYSHARED/.cache/composer/repo/flex/symfony-recipes-flex-main-index.json from cache
Reading /home/MYSHARED/.cache/composer/repo/flex/symfony-recipes-contrib-flex-main-index.json from cache
Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes/flex/main/index.json
Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/flex/main/index.json
[304] https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes-contrib/flex/main/index.json
[304] https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes/flex/main/index.json
Built pool.
Generating rules
Resolving dependencies through SAT
Looking at all rules.

Dependency resolution completed in 0.001 seconds
> pre-operations-exec: Symfony\Flex\Flex->recordOperations
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
> pre-autoload-dump: Google\Task\Composer::cleanup
> post-autoload-dump: Symfony\Component\Runtime\Internal\ComposerPlugin->updateAutoloadFile
122 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
> post-install-cmd: Symfony\Flex\Flex->install

Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.

> post-install-cmd: @auto-scripts
> auto-scripts: Symfony\Flex\Flex->executeAutoScripts
Executing script cache:clear
Executed script cache:clear  [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
```

Comment: Symfony 7 requiere PHP 8.2 o superior segun el "composer.json", yo recientemente inicie un proyecto con esta versión y la doc me solicitaba PHP 8.3.
A parte de esto, el comando `php -v` muestra la versión de PHP de la consola, puede ser diferente de la que ejecuta el servidor, *composer* en algun momento la tiene en cuenta. Puedes saber que versión se ejecuta con un "index.php" y la función `phpinfo` en la raiz del servidor, no obstante deberías poder consultarlo en la config del hosting.

Comment: parece problema de permiso en la cache XD

Comment: @Orici el problema era ese. La versión 8.2 se encontraba en esta ruta: `/usr/local/bin/ea-php82`. Lo he resuelto agregando la entrada: **`bin/php: '/usr/local/bin/ea-php82'`** en la sección `config` del archivo `deploy.yaml` y ahora el despliegue se hace correctamente.